# JMeter 403 Forbidden

Tags: api, jmeter, http-status-code-403, activemq-artemis

I have a problem with JMeter. When I try to send some request, it returns me a 403 Forbidden status code. I know that it needs an authentication, I've seen many things about that.

I'm working with Apache ActiveMQ Artemis. I need to execute some API request, which removes all messages in the queue. The API looks like that:

```
http://10.2.5.23:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22,component=addresses,address=%22TEST.GSH%22,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=%22anycast%22,queue=%22TEST.GSH%22/removeAllMessages()
```

When I try to execute it, it returns me a 403 Forbidden status code. I've tried to add HTTP Authorization Manager, added this url and typed username and password, but still it gives me the same output.

This is from where I login, also I added this in HTTP Authorization Manager and set the username and password. 
    http://10.2.5.23:8161/console/login

Any idea or advice will help me.

I know that here are questions like mine, but I have not found what would help me.

Comment: I've added an Authorization Header with Basic encoded, but now it says: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException

Comment: Why are you using JMeter to invoke the `removeAllMessages` management method? Are you running a performance test to see how long it takes to execute this management method? If so, why?

Comment: The queue fills very fast and most of information is not important and for that I must delete all messages.

Comment: What exactly are you testing? I ask because invoking `removeAllMessages` in general is an artificial way to deal with message accumulation that wouldn't be performed in a "normal" production situation. Typically clients would actually be consuming those messages.

Comment: I will try to explain what I am doing. We have a pushing service and it pushes too much test information into queue. For example I must update some table in database and then it should push into queue and I must verify if from db information was pushed correctly. I really don't know if someone does that or if does maybe I am doing it wrognly.

Comment: Where does your JMeter test fit into this?

Comment: I want to remove everything in the queue with API request of removingAll, then update table in database and after that, I must use browse operation from activemq. Well I know that it is really bad thing what I am trying to do, but I don't have any ideas more to solve that.

Comment: JMeter is a performance testing tool. Are you testing the performance of ActiveMQ Artemis + some database work? Also, I don't understand why you need to use the browse operation. Can you clarify that?

Comment: No, I am not testing the performance of ActiveMQ + database work. Well, I will try to clarify. When the queue will be empty, I should update a table in database, when I will do that it will be automatically pushed in queue, for example I updated TOP 5 in database, so in queue should be 5 messages. My job is to verify if everything was pushed correctly. If you have any ideas how should I do this anotherway, it will be very good. I know that JMeter is not for that what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. I've just added in HTTP Header Manager an authorization with Basic encoded. Now it works fine. But I have one question, why did HTTP Authorization Manager not work ? Why should i add authorization in header ? I can't make it only with HTTP Authorization Manager ?